# Ressources not loaded after setting CSP and CORP headers using Helmet

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy, helmet.js

Trying to make the web-app safer and force myself to control better future additions (JS and CSS assets on different CDNs), I'm running Helmet plugin in my Fastify (same as Express) web-app.

If I deactivate all Helmet controls like the following:
`fastify.register(helmet, false)` all works fine and all resources are loaded on client.

Then I tried to play (until exhaustion) with different configurations, nothing is working. The config and the browser error as the following:

```
{
    // contentSecurityPolicy: false,
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: { policy: 'same-site'}, 
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        ...require("fastify-helmet").contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        "default-src": ["'self'"],
        "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'unpkg.com', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net',
          'fonts.googleapis.com', 'use.fontawesome.com'],
        "script-src": ["'self'", 'unpkg.com', "cdn.jsdelivr.net", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "'data'", "*.tile.osm.org"],
        "font-src": ["'self'", 'fonts.googleapis.com', 'fonts.gstatic.com', 'use.fontawesome.com']
      },
    },
  };
```

Even setting

```
{ contentSecurityPolicy: false, crossOriginResourcePolicy: { policy: 'same-site'} }
```

with other variations of policy: same-origin, cross-origin none seems to work.

[image: errors]

As you can see, I'm running on LOCALHOST too and I didn't test elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: disable [the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy), enabled by default in Helmet v5.**

```js
{
  crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
  // ...
}
```

---

Helmet maintainer here.

Helmet sets the [the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy) to `require-corp`.

Setting this header means that loading cross-origin resources (like an image from another resource) is trickier. For example, loading a cross-origin like this...

```html
<img alt="My picture" src="https://example.com/image.png">
```

...won't work unless `example.com` explicitly allows it, by setting some response headers of its own. Your browser will try to load `example.com/image.png`, and if it's not explicitly allowed, your browser will drop the response.

To fix this, you can prevent Helmet from setting the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header, like this:

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    // ...
  })
);
```

I made [a small sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-rain-flk19?file=/src/index.js) you can use to play around with this.

Comment: Indeed, it works this way. +(1e+10) for taking time with explanations and the test example too.