# Getting "NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep" error with Helmet

Tags: node.js, helmet.js, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I'm seeing the following error in my browser console when using Helmet.js:

```
 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tl;dr: disable [the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy), enabled by default in Helmet v5.**

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    // ...
  })
);
```

---

Helmet v5 sets the [the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy) to `require-corp`. (This was possible in Helmet v4, but it was off by default, so most people didn't use it.)

Setting this header means that loading cross-origin resources (like an image from another resource) is trickier. For example, loading a cross-origin like this...

```html
<img alt="My picture" src="https://example.com/image.png">
```

...won't work unless `example.com` explicitly allows it, by setting some response headers of its own. Your browser will try to load `example.com/image.png`, and if it's not explicitly allowed, your browser will drop the response.

To fix this, you can prevent Helmet from setting the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header, like this:

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    // ...
  })
);
```

I made [a small sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-rain-flk19?file=/src/index.js) you can use to play around with this. In my testing, it doesn't seem to work in HTTP but it *does* over HTTPS, which might explain why things only break in production.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solution doesn't work in my case, then after so googling, I found a solution using helmet configuration like:

```
app.use(helmet.crossOriginEmbedderPolicy({ policy: "credentialless" }));
```