# net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200 Express.hs Helmet.js

Tags: node.js, express, helmet.js, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

```
const helmet = require("helmet");
app.use(helmet());
const scriptSrcUrls = [

];
const styleSrcUrls = [
  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/",
];
const connectSrcUrls = [
];
const fontSrcUrls = [
  "fonts.gstatic.com",
];
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      directives: {
          defaultSrc: [],
          connectSrc: ["'self'", ...connectSrcUrls],
          scriptSrc: ["'unsafe-inline'", "'self'", ...scriptSrcUrls],
          styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", ...styleSrcUrls],
          workerSrc: ["'self'", "blob:"],
          objectSrc: [],
          imgSrc: [
              "'self'",
              "blob:",
              "data:",
              "https://res.cloudinary.com/lullabay/",
              "https://images.unsplash.com/",
          ],
          fontSrc: ["'self'", ...fontSrcUrls],
      },
  })
);
```

Hi, I have a problem using Helmet.js, when the page loads, it loads without the mate image giving me this error:
GET https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudinaryaccount/image/fkdlasjfladsncw
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

at first, it gave it to me without all the images but as soon as I added `crossorigin =" anonymous started "` the images have a load correctly, the same result didn't happen with the meta image.

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904053/804100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep" error with Helmet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904052/getting-notsameoriginafterdefaultedtosameoriginbycoep-error-with-helmet)